# Openfire / Pidgin - The connection to the server was lost: The remote user has ended the connection

Tags: java, ubuntu, xmpp, openfire, pidgin

I created a Openfire server into ubuntu. Next I created the users. The connection from Pidgin client does not work and show the message "The connection to the server was lost: The remote user has ended the connection."

I enabled a debug logging on openfire. The following error is shown:

```
2016.05.04 10:06:20 org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler - Unexpected exception from SSLEngine.closeInbound(). 
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack? 
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208) 
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1639) 
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1607) 
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.closeInbound(SSLEngineImpl.java:1537) 
at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler.destroy(SslHandler.java:204) 
at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter.sessionClosed(SslFilter.java:439) 
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextSessionClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:382) 
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$900(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:47) 
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.sessionClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:750) 
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.sessionClosed(IoFilterAdapter.java:88) 
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextSessionClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:382) 
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.fireSessionClosed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:375) 
at org.apache.mina.core.service.IoServiceListenerSupport.fireSessionDestroyed(IoServiceListenerSupport.java:244) 
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.removeNow(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:600) 
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.removeSessions(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:560) 
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$800(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:67) 
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1132) 
at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
2016.05.04 10:06:20 org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterEvent - Event EXCEPTION_CAUGHT has been fired for session 220 
2016.05.04 10:06:20 org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor - Adding event SESSION_CLOSED to session 220 
Queue : [MESSAGE_SENT, , SESSION_CLOSED, ]
```

Can someone help me, please ? Thanks a lot!